# Passing a socket to a new AppDomain

Tags: c#, sockets, appdomain

I'm working on porting a client/server application to .NET.  The current C version of the server has one executable for a process (a Windows service) that listens for socket connections.  When the listener accepts a socket connection it spawns a new process to handle that connection.  The handler application is a separate executable.

In the .NET version of this application, I'd like to have one executable/process.  The listener should create a new AppDomain for each connection (to isolate the "worker process" assigned to each client).  How should I pass the socket from the listener app domain to the worker app domain?

Thanks!

Comment: Depending on the isolation you might be able to use GetData and SetData on the respective domains but you might have to Marshal the objects across. Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: I think I just found the answer to my own question.  The DuplicateAndClose method can be used even though I'm not passing the socket to a separate process.  The listener can just pass in its own process ID.

[link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/malarch/archive/2005/12/14/503884.aspx)

Comment: Cool, hope it works properly; if it does then you should answer your own question and accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I just found the answer to my own question.  The DuplicateAndClose method can be used even though I'm not passing the socket to a separate process.  The listener can just pass in its own process ID to DuplicateAndClose.

The solution is described here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/malarch/archive/2005/12/14/503884.aspx

This also works if you want to pass the socket off to a separate process.